# When does $.ajax call success in synchronous and asynchronous request?

Tags: jquery

Is there a difference in when `$.ajax()` calls its `success` function depending on if I have `async` set to `true` or `false`?

Answer (score 0):

Success is called after the webpage queried returns all its information to the browser without error.  i.e. http 200, 206, etc.  if it receives an error i.e. 404, 500 it calls error instead